# Find only two decimals

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am very new to Excel, a beginner! I need a formula/macro to find 1-2 decimals in a column. The column contains job codes for all levels of the organization. It would look something like this:

```
xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
xx.xxx.xxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I need to find only the job codes with one or two decimals, which specify a certain position in the organization, the end result looking like this:

```
xx.xxx
xx.xxx.xxx
xx.xxx.xxx
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a helper column to count the occurrence of `.` and then just filter this column:

`=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))`

Answer (score 2):

To Do it without a helper column:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$9,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$9)-ROW($A$2)+1)/(LEN($A$2:$A$9)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$9,".",""))<=2),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]